# C++ 11 initialization with auto

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

In C++ 11, we're encouraged to use auto for variable type,
does this also apply when initializing type like class and vector?

I mean should we write the following:

```
auto a = 10; 
auto b = MyClass();
auto c = vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
```

instead of:

```
auto a = 10;
MyClass b;
vector<int> c = {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: please don't. you already wrote the type, so there's no point using `auto`.

Comment: Herb Sutter strongly recommends the usage of `auto`. See the following article [GotW #94 Solution: AAA Style (Almost Always Auto)](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)

Comment: @KarolyHorvarth your answer really makes sense, but the link given by nosid argues "auto" results in a cleaner code ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`auto` is just a handy shortcut to simplify things like

```
VeryLongClassName *object = new VeryLongClassName();
```

Now it will be

```
auto *object = new VeryLongClassName();
```

There is no reason to write

```
auto a = 10; 
auto b = MyClass();
auto c = vector<int>();
```

because it is longer and harder to read than

```
int a = 10;
MyClass b;
vector<int> c;
```

Comment: Thanks, I really think your answer makes sense. However, in the link given by @nosid, Herb Sutter really encourages "auto" for almost everything. So, I think I will try this style for a while and see whether it impacts my productivity or not ...

Comment: Okay, I have read Herb Sutter. He gives three reasons to **almost** always use auto: laziness, commitment, readability. And I totally agree with him. But none of these reasons are shown in you code sample. If you are truely lazy, you will not write more complex code, which is less readable :) Your sample shows the **almost**, not the **always** part.

Comment: @mas.morozov, Using auto a, b and c are aligned, getting more **readability** IMHO

Comment: Actually in Part 5, he gives similar example ```auto e = employee{ empid }; auto w = widget{ 12, 34 };```

Comment: @Zhen - Maybe... in the block of 3 declarations and if you prefer it :)

Comment: `auto e = employee{ empid }; auto w = widget{ 12, 34 };` are simplier than `employee e = employee{ empid }; widget w = widget{ 12, 34 };` Variant `employee e(empid)` could require making constructor for `employee`. So, if _something_ urges you to write type name on the right - `auto` is definitely the choice.

Comment: @user350954 And no matter what HE or SHE the great have said, coding style choice is the matter your common sence and taste :) and often the matter of team working culture

Comment: @mas.morozov I see, thanks. Totally agree on your last comment!